# unhandled exception Access violation writing location in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, access-violation, unhandled-exception

Is there a way in Visual Studio 2005 to find out which pointer or variable is causing this access violation? I tried to run in debug mode and break when it happens. By looking at the call stacks, it happens in the end of the function (see below). Could using try/catch be able to find out which pointer it is?

**EDIT:**
Posting my code:

There is a Qt line edit and a checkbox in my application. Toggling the checkbox would switch the data format in the line edit. Like 3'b111 <==> 3'h7. Below is the callback function that is connected to the checkbox stateChanged signal. The exception happens in the end of function, when destructing local variables.

```
// switch hex/binary format. 15'h0000 <==> 15'b000000000000000
void switchDataFormat(int checkState) {
    QLineEdit* writeRegLE = this->getWriteRegLineEdit();
    string oldText = writeRegLE->text().toStdString();
    string newText = "";
    int maxLength;
    string regLengthText = oldText.substr(0, oldText.find('\''));
    string regValueText = oldText.substr(oldText.find('\'')+2);
    int regLength = this->getRegLength();

    if (checkState == Qt::Unchecked) {
        // switch to binary format
        maxLength = regLengthText.size() + 2 + regLength;
        string binaryText;
        for (int i = 0; i < regValueText.size(); ++i) {
            binaryText += hexToBinary(regValueText[i]);
        }
        newText = regLengthText + "'b" + binaryText.substr(binaryText.size()-regLength);  // trimming leading zeros to fit regLength
    }
    else {
        // switch to hex format
        maxLength = regLengthText.size() + 2 + regLength/4 + 1;
        newText = regLengthText + "'h";
        // zero filling to 4*n bits
        if (regLength%4 != 0) regValueText = string(regLength%4,'0') + regValueText;
        for (int i = 0; i < regValueText.size(); i+=4) {
            newText += binaryToHex(regValueText.substr(i,4));
        }
    }

    writeRegLE->setMaxLength(maxLength);
    writeRegLE->setText(QString::fromUtf8(newText.c_str()));
}
```

Comment: Post the offending code. Also, in debug mode, set a breakpoint a bit before you know the problem occurs, and then keep going through the code one step at a time, it may reveal your problem.

Comment: @user1264727: the code is too complicated, I will try to post it with a simpler version. I "step into" "void operator delete( void * p )" and now can see the pointer causing violation. How should I know what that pointer is pointing to?

Comment: VS will show you if you move your mouse over `p` there, but it sounds like you're deleting a pointer that should not be deleted. Figure out why. Maybe you have double deletion - deleting a pointer which has already been deleted, and that is a bad idea. If you can, post a minimal example that reproduces the problem. Or at least the code to your function from which the crash happens.

Comment: Where exactly do you destruct local variables?

Comment: Using VS debugger step through the code, the exception happens after step over the last line of the function "}", and in the "delete ( void * p )".